# How to do nothing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty statement in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234871/empty-statement-in-t-sql)

How can I get this to compile in SQL Server?

```
IF @value IS NULL
BEGIN
  -- I don't want to do anything here
END
```

Comment: why would you ever want this?

Comment: Because sometimes you just do.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a placeholder in a `BEGIN`/`END` block while you build out the SQL around it.

Comment: There may be some conditions as part of an if/else chain for which the required course of action is "do nothing".

Comment: This is also helpful to add an extra GO before a CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, or CREATE VIEW statement so that file header comments don't end up in your schema.

Comment: This is useful when you need to `CATCH` some errors and "do nothing" if it's a specific error you want to ignore. Like `BEGIN CATCH ; IF ERROR_NUMBER()==2601 DO NOTHING ; END CATCH`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You mean it fails because of the empty BEGIN-END? do something meaningless but syntactically valid if for some reason you cant remove the block;

```
IF @value IS NULL
BEGIN
  set @value=@value -- or print 'TODO' etc
END
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. In PL/SQL I can write `NULL;` but here is this the best I can do?

Comment: I cant think of anything that is not some kind of operation

Answer (score 18):

Based on the idea from [this thread](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/79580-SQL-Server-2000-no-op):

```
IF @value IS NULL
BEGIN
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00'
END
```

Should be noted (didn't know at first) that, like PRINT, this method is not universal. In particular, it cannot be used in functions. Use other suggestions when you need to add a NO-OP somewhere in a function.

Answer (score 14):

My first answer.

```
IF @value IS NULL BEGIN 
    goto a a:
END
```

Second answer after thinking a bit

```
IF @value IS NULL BEGIN 
    SET
END
```

Comment: The second one doesn't compile on my SQL Server 2008 R2. However, +1 for the first one, it's quite a novel idea (to me, anyway).

Comment: @Andriym you are right, it doesn't work on stack exchange eather. It did however work on one of my work databases. Really odd. The Work database is ms sqlserver 2008 as well.

Comment: @AndriyM my second surgestion works on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   
Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600:) 
compatibility_level = 80

Comment: Verified, worked for me too, and also in SQL Server 2005 with the same compatibility level. This is probably SQL Server 2000 thing.

Comment: You don't even need the `goto`, a label alone is enough: `IF @value IS NULL BEGIN nothing: END`.

Comment: That empty `SET` thing doesn't work on SQL Server 2017

Comment: @LukasEder correct, but it worked on older versions, read the comment from AndriyM.

Comment: Michel de Ruiter's comment is actually the best answer

Comment: @WadeHatler I agree

Answer (score 4):

The only things I can think of are operations that are very fast and don't affect disk.  The easiest and fastest are probably variable declarations and assignments...

```
DECLARE @t int
```

OR

```
SET @t=@t
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IF @value IS NULL
BEGIN
  -- I don't want to do anything here
  Print 'What a waste of time'
END
```

Comment: But that does something other than nothing!

Answer (score -3):

The question in my mind is: why would you put that in your code?  If the reason is that you have an else block, then flip the condition to "if @value is not null".  By itself though, this block doesn't do anything.

Comment: What if you have 4 other `IF ELSE ...` conditions and you want to make it clear that in the first case you do nothing; do you wrap that all in a negated `IF` block and increase the level of nesting? Believe me, sometimes this is not the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @B Tyler: If you want to include the NULL case in your code, then update your question to show it is in the scope of 4 other IF ELSE statements. Otherwise, the questions is misleading and everyone will ask why you even want to do this.

Comment: @hardcore it can also be part of dynamic sql where no process is required in certain circumstances.

Comment: @B: that's what comments are for.  Just put two dashes and start writing  whatever the native language of the developers is.

Comment: Inverting the IF statement isn't always clear or straightforward especially when NULL is involved.  As a simple contrived example `IF @x=1 AND @y=0` would have to invert to `IF @x <> 1 AND @x IS NOT NULL AND @y <> 0 AND @y IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Case in point, I inverted that wrong, it would be `IF @x <> 1 OR @x IS NULL OR @y <> 0 OR @y IS NULL`