# SQL Server stored procedure with empty body

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

[CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) syntax:

```
CREATE { PROC | PROCEDURE } [schema_name.] procedure_name [ ; number ]   
    [ { @parameter [ type_schema_name. ] data_type }  
        [ VARYING ] [ = default ] [ OUT | OUTPUT | [READONLY]  
    ] [ ,...n ]   
[ WITH <procedure_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
[ FOR REPLICATION ]   
AS { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }  
[;]  


<sql_statement> ::=   
{ [ BEGIN ] statements [ END ] }
```

> **[ ]** (brackets)    **Optional syntax items.** Do not type the brackets.
>
> **{ }** (braces)  **Required syntax items.** Do not type the braces.

And human readable form:

[image]

Let's try to write stored procedure with empty body:

```
CREATE PROC my_proc AS

-- please treat it as separate call, for example with different session
EXEC my_proc
```

is perfect valid syntax.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/IRRHZ62887)**</kbd>

So it looks like that `sql_statement` could be empty.

Now let's try the same with but this time with `BEGIN/END` block:

```
CREATE PROC my_proc AS
BEGIN
END
-- Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/TPN49602)**</kbd>

Why is the first example valid? If `sql_statement` allows nothing then second example should work too  or the doc is inaccurate.

**EDIT**

> well, that's because in the first example it isn't an empty body, your sp will be: EXEC my_proc

The case was to show that I could call SP. But you could add `GO` or use `EXEC`:

```
CREATE PROC my_proc AS
GO

EXEC my_proc
```

or

```
EXEC('CREATE PROC my_proc AS')

EXEC my_proc
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](http://rextester.com/NIE90805)**</kbd>

Comment: well, that's because in the first example it isn't an empty body, your sp will be: `EXEC my_proc`. It's the same as if you write: `CREATE PROC my_proc AS BEGIN EXEC my_proc END`

Comment: It's not just the SPROC. Executing `BEGIN END` in a query windows throws the error as well, but executing an empty string works successfully.

Comment: @Lamak Nope, try without it or with `EXEC` block

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954336/how-to-do-nothing-in-sql-server

Comment: Probably it allows the completely  empty body for backward compatibility and not worth fixing. Same as a trailing comma is allowed after the final column in a `create table`.

Comment: @MartinSmith This could be the case.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax error is not related to the proper syntax for stored procs. It is the proper syntax for "BEGIN/END". BEGIN/END requires some SQL inside of it to be valid. The documentation for BEGIN/END shows this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx

```
BEGIN  
     {   
    sql_statement | statement_block   
     }   
END
```

The grammar in the CREATE PROC documentation is indeed not fully correct, as it says that sql_statement is required for "CREATE PROC", when it is actually not required.

Comment: Ok, then the doc for CREATE SP is inaccurate. Please look at railroad diagram.

Comment: But this is the same as the grammar in the OP. And there it accepts an empty string for `sql_statement` so this doesn't really answer the question. You are just asserting that this is a non empty string. `sql_statement` is not optional in the `CREATE PROC` grammar with or without `BEGIN.. END`.

Comment: @lad2025 - I would say the doc isn't really inaccurate, just not recursively detailed. That is to say, it defines that you can use "BEGIN" optionally, but it doesn't define what a valid syntax for "BEGIN" is. Similarly, it says you can include "sql_statement", but doesn't define what "sql_statements" are valid.

Comment: @MartinSmith "sql_statement is not optional in the CREATE PROC grammar with or without BEGIN.. END". This is incorrect. "create proc testing as" by itself is valid and creates an empty proc.

Comment: @GendoIkari yes it works. Hence the question. You seem to have missed the point of the question.

Comment: @MartinSmith I must be misunderstanding your comment then, because you said "sql_statement is not optional in the CREATE PROC grammar", but that is not true...

Comment: The grammar is the written Backus Naur supplied in the question. The question is why the behaviour in practice differs from that. So arguing that "it executes so the grammar must say that" is not an answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok I see now; thought you were saying that it's not optional within valid SQL Syntax. I got mixed up on which of the 2 examples the OP was saying was incorrect.